# How can I see the amount of memory a process is using and not just has allocated?

Tags: windows, memory, monitoring, memory-usage

I am looking for a way to determine the memory a process is really using (not just having allocated).

Looking at procmon.exe or vmmap.exe the relevant values are:

**Private bytes**
All memory allocated.

**Working set**
Used memory in physical RAM.

Assume `private bytes = 3 GB` and the `working set = 200 MB`. In the best case the process is using only the 200 MB and the rest is just allocated and not used. In the worst case it uses all 3 GB an 2,8 GB are swapped to the pagefile.

(I read the questions [How much memory is my windows app really using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166502/how-much-memory-is-my-windows-app-really-using) and [What is private bytes, virtual bytes, working set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set) but they don't answer my question.)

Is there any way to find the real uses memory of the process?

**Edit:**
For me is used memory is the amount of allocated memory which have been filled.

When jus allocating 3 GB 'nothing' happens. The memory is just reserved for the process. The private bytes increase but the working set keeps unchanged. After filling 200 MB of the allocated memory it is shown on the working set.

This 200 MB of used / filled memory is what I look for, regardless of beeing completely on the Working set or having been swapped out.

Comment: What is your definition of *memory a process is using*?

Comment: @gronostaj edited the post, thx.

Comment: The OS doesn't keep track of whether the memory that has been allocated has been written to or not. It keeps track of what pages are currently in physical RAM (Working Set) and how much has been allocated (Private bytes).  I don't think you can find what you're looking for at an OS level, it would be an application specific function.

Comment: @heavyd The system knows what pages, which aren't in the Working Set, have already been written. This can easyliy be monitored.

Comment: This is a good question.  I, too, am confused by what those columns are supposed to represent, and whether it's possible to have more insight into the swap space used by a process.  It looks like it's basically not.  http://superuser.com/questions/917492/whats-the-total-amount-of-memory-and-swap-a-process-is-using

Comment: Private bytes s not "all memory that's been allocated". There is allocated memory other than process-private memory. Most of it is called "mapped".